# Swift: How do I subclass an object so that I can add an extra variable?

Tags: swift, oop

I am building an app using a 3rd party framework and they have a default object (called `JSQMessage`) that has 3 parameters (`id`, `text`, and `displayName`):

```
func addMessage(id: String, text: String, displayName: String) {
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: displayName, text: text)
        messages.append(message) 
}
```

I want to add another parameter to the object called `score` as such:

```
func addMessage(id: String, text: String, displayName: String, score: Int) {

        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: displayName, text: text, score: score)
        messages.append(message)
}
```

However I keep getting the error `Argument labels '(senderId:, displayName:, text:, score:)' do not match any available overloads`

I know that I must subclass the JSQMessage object and add my extra variable to your subclassed object...except I do not know how to do this.

I have created a new subclass of JSQMessage called `CustomMessage.swift` and it looks like such:

```
class CustomMessage: JSQMessage {

}
```

Now how do I go about adding an extra parameter to the object?

Note that the object looks like this: `JSQMessage(id: String, text: String, displayName: String)`

But I want it to accept another parameter like this:
`JSQMessage(id: String, text: String, displayName: String, score: Int)`

I would appreciate it a lot if somebody could help me out here.

P.S. Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Can you write the value of `let message`?

Comment: let message is a JSQMessage object, and it is where I get the error

Comment: When you call `let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: displayName, text: text)`, what is the value of `message`? I mean with the original constructor

Comment: `JSQMessage(id: String, text: String, displayName: String)`

Comment: When you're tempted to ask about simple syntax, you really should read a bit about how to use the language first.  Page 18 of Apple's free Swift 2.2 book: "Subclasses include their superclass name after their class name, separated by a colon".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new class. The syntax would be something like

```
class MyMessage : JSQMessage {
}
```

You would add your extra attribute to the class

```
class MyMessage : JSQMessage {
    var score : Int
}
```

[I'm guessing that your `score` is an `Int` here.]

Then you would need to add an initializer

```
class MyMessage : JSQMessage {
    var score : Int

    init(senderID:Int, displayName:String, text:String, score:Int) {
        self.score = score
        super.init(senderID:senderID, displayName:displayName, text:text)
    }
}
```

If you're having trouble with this kind of thing then I **strongly** recommend that you spend some time with Apple's free book [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/), because this is basic Swift stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the entire "Ask Question" page was had "Read the Language Guide" written everywhere?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one last question, what does the error `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'JSQMessage'` mean? I can't seem to find a definite answer. And yeah I guess I just jumped into development without reading the guides. My bad.

Comment: Every class has one or more `init` methods that are "designated" initializers, and you must call one of them when creating an instance. I used the initializer that you mentioned, but it might not be a designated initializer. The documentation for a class should indicate which initializers are designated.

Comment: Also see [Designated Initializers and Convenience Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

Comment: @TomHarrington hiii i also need help i also want to created a message id

Comment: i used the same way u given example but it didnot worked i m getting only bydefault parameters value